# Unable to test a method with JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I'm unable to test the hasNext() method in the IterableIntegerArrays class. If I call this method in IterableIntegerArraysTestCases, it says "cannot find symbol". How should I resolve this error?

```
public class IterableIntegerArrays extends IntegerRelation implements Iterable<IntPair> {

    public IterableIntegerArrays(int n) {
        super(n);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<IntPair> iterator() {

    return new Iterator<IntPair>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            //implementation
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public IntPair next() {
            //implementation
        }

    };       

    }

}
```

-

```
public abstract class IterableIntegerArraysTestCases extends IntegerRelationTestCases {

    protected Iterable<IntPair> iterable;

    protected void setIterable(final int n) {
        setInstance(n);
        iterable = ((Iterable<IntPair>) instance);
    }

    private void checkHasNext(int a, int b, boolean expResult) {
        boolean result = iterable.hasNext(); //It says "cannot find symbol" here
        assertEquals("hasNext(" + a + ", " + b + ")", expResult, result);
    }

}
```

Comment: `iterable` is an `Iterable`, it doesn't have `hasNext`. Only `Iterator` have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) does not have `hasNext` method . Its `Iterator` which has `hasNext` method. You should do

```
    iterable.iterator().hasNext()
```